# Store a text in encrypted form and use in powershell script without compromising it to other users?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I want to encrypt a text which I want to use in different PowerShell script without compromising its security as other user will be using scripts that will contain that text. Basically I want to conceal that text from everybody and use it without any hassle to all PowerShell scripts that are using that particular text. Text can be stored in a file so that it will be used in different scripts. I have tried basic things like :

```
$text = Read-Host "Enter the text" -AsSecureString

$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($text)

$Plaintext = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
Write-Host "Text is: " $PlainText
```

But the thing is it can easily be found if you are in same computer. I need some foolproof method if any.This is my first question so please ignore my mistakes, if any.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you need a specific key to make the string encrypted.

*For Setting the Key*:

```
function Set-Key {
param([string]$string)
$length = $string.length
$pad = 32-$length
if (($length -lt 16) -or ($length -gt 32)) {Throw "String must be between 16 and 32 characters"}
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
$bytes = $encoding.GetBytes($string + "0" * $pad)
return $bytes
}
```

*For Setting the Encrypted Data:*

```
function Set-EncryptedData {
param($key,[string]$plainText)
$securestring = new-object System.Security.SecureString
$chars = $plainText.toCharArray()
foreach ($char in $chars) {$secureString.AppendChar($char)}
$encryptedData = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureString -Key $key
return $encryptedData
}
```

*For Decrypting the data:*

```
function Get-EncryptedData {
param($key,$data)
$data | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key |
ForEach-Object {[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($_))}
}
```

How to use:

```
$plainText = "Some Super Secret Password"
$key = Set-Key "AGoodKeyThatNoOneElseWillKnow"
$encryptedTextThatIcouldSaveToFile = Set-EncryptedData -key $key -plainText $plaintext
$encryptedTextThatIcouldSaveToFile  ## - sample output 507964ed3a197b26969adead0212743c378a478c64007c477efbb21be5748670a7543cb21135ec324e37f80f66d17c76c4a75f6783de126658bce09ef19d50da
$DecryptedText = Get-EncryptedData -data $encryptedTextThatIcouldSaveToFile -key $key
$DecryptedText
```

Reference Link: [Encrypting & Decrypting Strings with PS](http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/12/13/Encrypting-and-Decrypting-Strings-with-a-Key-in-PowerShell.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: but in this method how can we secure $key because $key is saved on my machine so anybody can decrypt that. I need a solution in which anybody can use script without knowing.

Comment: @geekybuddy just keep key in the file. $key = Set-Key -string (get-content file.txt)

Comment: but anybody can access the file because it is same system with same user.

Comment: @geekybuddy - Assuming your users of the script are allowed to know the key, you can use `Export-CliXml`/`Import-CliXml` to protect the key. Only the current user on the current machine kan decrypt the file containing the key. Drawback is that you can't deploy *one* keyfile on all machines. For each user on each machine, the file has to be created once.

Comment: @Lieven the thing is only one user is on the computer i.e Administrator and different people will use same account to run scripts. So how can we protect key from other people.

Comment: @geekybuddy - To recap, your users have to be able to run the script but are not allowed to know any secret to decrypt the data?! I assume you'd have to resort to [assymetric crypography](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/246071/description-of-symmetric-and-asymmetric-encryption) but that's far beyond what I'm comfortable making claims about *(fwiw, if you are running this localy in the user's account, no one is stopping them from taking a memory dump and extract secrets from there)*.

Comment: I think you'd better ask at the [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site and make sure you mention all the constraints. It's important to know that the users are not allowed to know *any* secret to decrypt data. *(and link this question if you do, I'm interested in any results that you might get)*

Comment: Thanks for your help . I will let you know.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I asked above question to security, one said it is not possible as same user account will be using same system.

Comment: @geekybuddy: Its possible. but only way is to have a dedicated key. Let me give you  my link from the Documentation-- [Handling Secrets](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/2917/handling-secrets-and-credentials/26943/storing-the-credentials-in-encrypted-form-and-passing-it-as-parameter-when-requi#t=201703160222065595737).

Comment: Can you explain because password file is still in system and AES key path is still in script one can go ahead and try to break the password using AES key and Password file.

Comment: But how the guy will get the key. That key is a dedicated one. You need the key to decrypt it. So when you are decrypting (may be a diff user) , that time you need the key.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - OP is not *(only)* trying to protect a secret from attackers compromising a users system but also from the user himself. The legitimate user running the script should not be asked for or know a key to decrypt *(correct geekybuddy?)*

Comment: Perhaps a webservice running your script could be an option?